# How to share Variables between Classes in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, smtp

I am currently trying to create a basic Gmail client, and I am trying to share my login details between two classes, `Authen` and `Application`. I need to access the credits entered in the `Authen` class, but I can't quite figure out how to do so. Here is my current code, in the class `Application`:

```
Username_mine = passcheck.Create_Widgets.Username.get()
Password_mine = passcheck.Create_Widgets.Password.get()
contents = self.Body.get("0.0", END)
FROM = "Unknown"
subject = self.Subject_Entry.get()
recipients = self.To_Entry.get()
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.login(Username_mine, Password_mine)
server.sendmail(FROM, recipients, contents)
```

When I run the code, I get the error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1410, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/Users/BigKids/Desktop/Coding/Python 2/Email/Email Send GUI V1.py", line 112, in send_cmd
    Username_mine = passcheck.Create_Widgets.Username.get()
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'Username'
```

Thank you in advance for the help.

**Edit** Here's my code:

```
#Email Send v3 Program. It has a basic GUI to send emails.

from Tkinter import *
import smtplib
import string
import random

def random_char():
    char_select = random.randrange(52)
    char_choice = string.ascii_letters[char_select]
    return char_choice

class Authen(Frame):
    """Holds authentication code and basic GUI stuff"""
    def __init__(self, master):
        """Start Authen GUI"""
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()
        self.Create_Widgets()

    def Create_Widgets(self):
        """Spawns the widgets"""
        self.Usertext = Label(self, text = "Username: ")
        self.Usertext.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
        self.Username = Entry(self)
        self.Username.grid(row = 0, column = 1)

        self.Passtext = Label (self, text = "Password: ")
        self.Passtext.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
        self.Password = Entry (self, show = "*")
        self.Password.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

        self.Submit = Button(self, text = "Submit Credits",
                        command = self.authen_credits)
        self.Submit.grid()

    def authen_credits(self):
        """Backbone of authen process"""
        Username_mine = self.Username.get()
        Password_mine = self.Password.get()
        server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
        server.ehlo()
        server.starttls()
        while True:
            try:
                server.login(Username_mine,Password_mine)
                #make my screen dimensions work
                w = 500
                h = 1000
                app = Application()
                app.title("SMTP Mail Client")
                app.geometry("%dx%d" % (w, h))
                break
            except smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError:
                print "Login Failed"

class Application(Toplevel):
    """Toplevel Frame, holds sendmail stuff"""
    def __init__(self):
        """Start the toplevel Frame"""
        Toplevel.__init__(self)
        self.grid()
        self.entryFun()
        self.mainFun()

    def entryFun(self):
        """Holds entry Frame"""
        self.entryFrame = Frame(self)
        self.entryFrame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = W)

        self.To_Lbl = Label(self.entryFrame, text = "TO:  ")
        self.To_Lbl.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = W)

        self.To_Entry = Entry(self.entryFrame)
        self.To_Entry.grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky = W)


        self.Subject_Lbl = Label(self.entryFrame, text = "Subject:  ")
        self.Subject_Lbl.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = W)

        self.Subject_Entry = Entry(self.entryFrame)
        self.Subject_Entry.grid(row = 1, column = 1, sticky = W)

    def mainFun(self):
        """Holds body of thing"""
        self.entryFrame = Frame(self)
        self.entryFrame.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = W)


        self.Body = Text(self.entryFrame, width = 75, height = 50, relief = GROOVE, bd = 5)
        self.Body.grid()

        self.send_mail = Button(self, text = "Send Mail",
                                command = self.send_cmd)
        self.send_mail.grid()

    def send_cmd(self):
        Username_mine = passcheck.Create_Widgets.Username.get()
        Password_mine = passcheck.Create_Widgets.Password.get()
        contents = self.Body.get("0.0", END)
        FROM = "Unknown"
        subject = self.Subject_Entry.get()
        recipients = self.To_Entry.get()
        server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
        server.ehlo()
        server.starttls()
        server.login()
        server.sendmail(FROM, recipients, contents)

root = Tk()
root.title("Login")
root.geometry("500x500")
passcheck = Authen(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You can pass to the constructor of  Application a reference to the class Authen. This way, Application can access the login details

Comment: You need to give more of your code, like the `Create_Widgets` function/class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting the error because`Create_Widgets()`is a method function of the `Authen` class, so the`self.Username = Entry(self)`in it is makes`Username`an attribute of the instance, not the method. Given that, and assuming `passcheck` is such an instance, I think you need to write:

```
Username_mine = passcheck.Username.get()
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that Username is an actual member of the **function** object?
(make sure that you are using **self.Username** instead of **Username** in the function class)

Answer (score 0):

Create_Widgets is a function not a class, so you can't access .Username in it.

What you need to do is pass the instance of Authen to the Application class, and store it, say in self.authen. Then functions in Application can do: self.authen.Username

From briefly skimming your code, perhaps you could modify your `__init__` for Application, such that it accepts an "authen" variable:

```
def __init__(self, authen):
  # Other stuff.
  self.authen=authen
```

You would then initialise Application with 
`app = Application(authen=self)`

And in `send_cmd()`, you would call: `Username_mine = self.authen.Username.get()`